# Power Query formula

Tags: powerquery

I would like to create a formula in power query

this is the data

```
value :                                              
High-back|low-back|Mid-back|No Back 

description:
Venus Comfort Mesh High-Back Fabric Chair.
```

I would like the query to look at the data under value and if its in the description the output should say "fix" How can I create that rule? so this example should say "fix" because High-back is in the description and the value. If you can help me create an output to say the High-back value  would be perfect.. can you show me both outputs?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

So, if I'm understanding you correctly, you are asking that if you have a table like this:

[image]...

You want to know how to derive this:

[image]

(This output example assumes you want to ignore text case.)

The answer is to add a new custom column with a formula like this:

[image]

(The `Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` is what causes this to ignore the text case. So if case matters, then remove the `, Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase` from the formula.)

Comment: Thank you for answering my question, but I noticed you removed the delimiters and had the values in different rows. Is there a way to extract that same data with the pipes still in the values?

Comment: I posted a second answer based on your comment/question.

Comment: This is perfect!!! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Is this output more in line with what you are asking, Shanna?

[image]

If so, here's one way to get there. Starting with this table:

[image]

Add an index column:

(Add Column -> Index Column)

[image]

Then split by delimiter, on the pipes:

(Home -> Split Column -> By Delimiter ->

[image] ->

OK)

[image]

Then make sure the value and description columns are text type:

(Select both the value and description columns then -> Home -> Data Type -> Text)

[image]

Add a column containing the result whether each row's description contains its value (has a value-description match):

(Add Column -> Custom Column ->

[image]  ->

OK)

[image]

Group on the Index column, using All Rows:

(Transform -> Group By ->

[image] ->

OK)

[image]

Add a column and identify whether the information in the row's grouped table has a value-description match listed in it by returning "fix" for the row:

(Add Column -> Custom Column ->

[image] ->

OK)

[image]

Merge the earlier table state from the applied step where the index column was added and the last state where the "fix" was (or wasn't) added for each row:

(You can set this up by clicking: Home -> Merge Queries ->

[image]
*Note that the second table that is selected here is the same table as the first, which is the current table.*

-> OK

[image]

Change the merge made above by editing the formula from:
`= Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Custom1", {"Index"}, #"Added Custom1", {"Index"}, "Added Custom1", JoinKind.LeftOuter)`
to
`= Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, #"Added Custom1", {"Index"}, "Added Custom1", JoinKind.LeftOuter)`)

[image]

Expand the tables in the Added Custom column from the merge:

(Click [image] ->

[image] ->

OK)

[image]

Remove the Index column:

(Select the Index column then -> Home -> Remove Columns)

[image]

Here's the M code for it:

```
let
    Source = Table1,
    #"Added Index" = Table.AddIndexColumn(Source, "Index", 0, 1, Int64.Type),
    #"Split Column by Delimiter" = Table.ExpandListColumn(Table.TransformColumns(#"Added Index", {{"value", Splitter.SplitTextByDelimiter("|", QuoteStyle.Csv), let itemType = (type nullable text) meta [Serialized.Text = true] in type {itemType}}}), "value"),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Split Column by Delimiter",{{"value", type text}, {"description", type text}}),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Changed Type", "Custom.1", each Text.Contains([description],[value],Comparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase)),
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(#"Added Custom", {"Index"}, {{"AllData", each _, type table [value=nullable text, description=text, Custom=table, Index=number, Custom.1=logical]}}),
    #"Added Custom1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "fix?", each if List.AnyTrue([AllData][Custom.1]) then "fix" else null),
    #"Merged Queries" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Added Index", {"Index"}, #"Added Custom1", {"Index"}, "Added Custom1", JoinKind.LeftOuter),
    #"Expanded Added Custom1" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Merged Queries", "Added Custom1", {"fix?"}, {"fix?"}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expanded Added Custom1",{"Index"})
in
    #"Removed Columns"
```